# Effect of single nucleotide deletion or insertion on primer annealing

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, pcr, snp, primer

How is primer annealing, and, consequently, PCR amplification **affected by single nucleotide deletion or insertion inside the primer ?**

Imagine a primer like this:  
GCGTCATAAAGGGGACGTG (primer)  
 and the corresponding part of template DNA has one G missing, so it looks like this:  
GCGTCATAAAGGGACGTG (template).

The possible pairing could be  
GCGTCATAAAGGGGACGTG primer  
GCGTCATAAA_GGGACGTG template  
or  
GCGTCATAAAGGGGACGTG primer  
GCGTCATAAAGGG_ACGTG template  
 or anything in between.

Is it possible that amplification with such primer would be completely disrupted in normal real time PCR at 60°C annealing? Could this completely disrupt the amplification?

If the mismatch was **substitution**-like, I would be pretty confident, the primer would be still functional and amplification would occur. In the extreme case, it would be at least residual amplification at late Ct. There are a lot of data, how substitution mismatches affect primers and I also have a lot of personal experience with that.

Unfortunately, the **deletion** mismatches are less studied plus googleproof. The only indication I have found is this work:  
Lipsky RH, Mazzanti CM, Rudolph JG, Xu K, Vyas G, Bozak D, et al. DNA melting analysis for detection of single nucleotide polymorphisms. Clin Chem. 2001;47:635-44.  
In that work, single nucleotide deletion had similar or lower affect on melting temperature than substitution mismatch. But it was about longer oligos.  Examples:  
Effect of deletion:  
133 bp fragment, 67 % GC, deletion SNP at position 43, delta Tm (homo-hetero duplex) = 1.2°C  
Effects of substitutions:  
152 bp fragment, 43 % GC, substitution T to C at position 68, delta Tm (homo-hetero duplex) = 0.9°C  
100 bp fragment, 41 % GC, substitution T to C at position 42, delta Tm (homo-hetero duplex) = 1.4°C  
163 bp fragment, 60 % GC, substitution C to T at position 86, delta Tm (homo-hetero duplex) = 2.2°C  
110 bp fragment, 59 % GC, substitution G to A at position 66, delta Tm (homo-hetero duplex) = 3.8°C

**Questions**:  
1. Can you recommend me literature about how deletion mismatches inside (not at the very end of !!!) primers affect annealing and PCR ?  
2. Would You guess the primer in my example would be still functional , at least partly, or would You expect no amplification at all ?

---

**EDIT after your inputs:**  
This online application " mfold.rna.albany.edu/?q=DINAMelt/Two-state-melting " thinks, deletion mismatches are more destabilising than substitutions, at least for short primers. For my own example, it calculated delta Tm (homo-hetero duplex) = 12.9°C .
If I try substitution mismatches instead, delta Tm (homo-hetero duplex) is in interval 3,8°C to 5,7°C.

**New question**  
 If you have experience as similar as possible to my case, which is 19 nt long primer with single nucleotide deletion in the comlementary template at position cca 6 - 9 from 3' primer end, annealing temperature used at 60°C, please let me know if You achieved amplification or not.  Please, give me a respective reference, if you have it, so I will quote it in my review :-) .

Also, I am still interested in general info, as long as the topic is narrow enough to be about single nucleotide deletions or insertions in primers. (Not substitution mismatches).

Comment: primers would be functional as long as the 3'ends match properly and the mismatch is not huge. You can calculate the changed melting temperature using UNAfold DNA-DNA hybridization server.

Comment: Very neat application, thanks ! For the benefit of others - I have found where exactly one enters the sequences at the server: http://mfold.rna.albany.edu/?q=DINAMelt/Two-state-melting

Comment: Similar to @Chris, I've used longer, even ultra-mers to cause deletions.  I've been curious about how small I could make the primers, but I've always had the luxury of being able to make them pretty long without worrisome 2ndary structures.  Have you considered trying this on a test template to see how it goes?  Wouldn't be too costly to test (I've considered it).

Answer (score 4):

We used this kind of primers to generate out of frame mutations or to add additional bases. In my experience your PCR will work (probably a a lower efficiency) and you will get a product with an additional base. We used primers with bigger differences in PCR based site directed mutagenesis of plasmids, there up to 10 bases didn't match but the primers where also longer. For single nucleotide mismatches (either + or - one base) we used primers around this size.

Regarding the literature, this publications might be useful:

- [A guide to the design and use of mismatched and degenerate
  primers](http://genome.cshlp.org/content/3/4/S39.full.pdf+html)
- [Effects of primer-template mismatches on the polymerase chain
  reaction: Human immunodeficiency virus type 1 model studies](http://nar.oxfordjournals.org/content/18/4/999.short)
- [The Effects of Internal Primer-Template Mismatches on RT-PCR: HIV-1
  Model Studies](http://nar.oxfordjournals.org/content/25/3/654.full)
- [Effect of primer mismatch, annealing temperature and PCR cycle number
  on 16S rRNA gene-targetting bacterial community analysis](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1574-6941.2007.00283.x/abstract)

Especially the first publication contains a lot of other interestings references.

Comment: If you do not wory about your identity, would you mind sending me a reference for your publication, where there was primer of this size (cca 19 nt), had a single nucleotide deletion or insertion, and still worked ? ( Iknow I am probably too demanding, because you have sent me 4 publications already. It would just be convenient to have reference for this specific example right away).

Comment: No big deal: Look at this [paper](http://hmg.oxfordjournals.org/content/22/21/4357.abstract?sid=0d175914-c41b-444d-b977-d220df683a88), the sequences are in the supplemental data. The shortest primer pairs are 25mers. The length is dictated by the surrounding sequence.

Comment: @Barbara What I forgot: I recently used sligtly shorter primers (21 and 22mers) but this results are not published yet.

Comment: @ Chris: Thanks, at least I have assurance, it can work this way. But if by chance you'll remember you have a poster presentation where those short primers are mentioned, please, let me know.

Comment: @ Chris again: The articles you listed say nothing about single nucleotide deletions, with the exception of Kwok 2014, which says minimum. (Kwok says, the primers can be used to indtroduce indel SNP and that they should be placed in the middle of 24 - 36 base oligo.) Your own article mentions only long (46 nt) oligos spanning 3nt indel. Am I overlooking something ?

Comment: Yes, you do. In the supplemental document there are 25mers documented.

Comment: @ Chris  The only 25 nt long primers are N278D-F and N278D-R. Blasting them against nrnt database shows, that N278D-F has a central G, where most mice have A. N278D-R has a central C, where most mice have T. It looks like substitution mismatches, not indels. (Limiting blast to Homo sapiens does not give good primer matches). In which primer is an indel mismatch and which template should I blast it against to see the indel myself ?

Comment: I never talked about indels, for this purpose you will need longer oligos. This short primer was used to introduce a point mutation. Which worked quite well according to our sequencing results.

Comment: @ Chris  Where does the information come from, that (single nucleotide) indels are more destabilising to annealing than substitutions ? (Maybe we use different definition of indel and point mutation. What I was talking about are single nucleotide insertions or deletions. But not substitutions)

Comment: what do _you_ mean by indels ? In your vocabulary, is single nucleotide deletion or insertion a subtype of indel ?

Comment: I name this small changes point mutations (when we only change one nucleotide to another to express a different amino acid). Otherwise I stick to the definition of indel, that you find in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indel): "In germline and somatic mutation studies, indel describes a special mutation class, defined as a mutation resulting in both an insertion of nucleotides and a deletion nucleotides which results in a net change in the total number of nucleotides, where both changes are nearby on the DNA."

Comment: Your answer confuses me further. For clarity, let us just speak about **frame shift** mutations caused by only one nucleotide insertion or deletion. Do you have citation about 25 nucleotide long (or shorter) primer, which harbors single nucleotide-based frameshift mutation in the middle ?

Comment: I haven't done frame shift mutations since this doesn't occur in the transcription factor would analyze (it would be embryonical lethal). What we have done is to introduce point mutations (exchanging single nucleotides against others) and here relatively short primers can work (the N278D mutation in the paper mentioned above is done with a 25mer).

Comment: Thanks. Now, which part of Your main answer (not comments) pertains to single nucleotide-based **frameshift** mutation ? Did you previously work with cca 19-22 nucleotide long primer with single nucleotide-based **frameshift** mutation in the middle ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding another reference. This group looks at the effect of different mismatches (e.g. A>T vs A>G) and also looks at positional effects.

> Our results show that single mismatches instigate a broad variety of
>   effects, ranging from minor (<1.5 cycle threshold, eg, A–C, C–A, T–G,
>   G–T) to severe impact (>7.0 cycle threshold, eg, A–A, G–A, A–G, C–C)
>   on PCR amplification. A clear relationship between specific mismatch
>   types, position, and impact was found.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2797725/

Comment: I was interested in deletions, not substitutions. No matter how much stress this out, people keep sending me info about substitutions in every forum ever.